# Libraries VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Good evening

I'm trying to set up a development environment on my newly Boot-Camped Windows 10.

I know how to link the include/lib in VS. On my Mac all my external libraries and include files are at either:
/use/local/ or /opt/local/

I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to do this on windows, or are there a way to force VS to always look in a particular dir?

Cheers

Comment: You can configure all the paths you need in your [Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx).

Comment: It is not the Microsoft way.  When they sell software then their expectation is that customers use it for a long time, 20 years is not unusual.  But still consider buying newer versions with differences in the include files.  Or a dev needs to do the same for his customers, XP is very hard to get rid of for example.  So these files are stored in different directories.  The VS installer takes care of it, nothing you have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS has the concept of [property sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) which basically are a predefined set of properties for your project. Every C++ project includes by default few property sheets and there's even a special property sheet called *Microsoft.Cpp.[Platform].user* where *[Platform]* is either Win32 or x64. By editing the contents of this file you can set the paths for all your projects (or other arbitrary values such as macros).

To edit these files do either of the following:

1. Make a new CPP project in VS. Go to *View*->*Other Windows*->*Property Manager*. This will show a new pane in the current window and from there you can find the property sheet and edit as you see fit. This approach has the benefit of being more user-friendly as VS provides some nice GUI. Here's one [tutorial](http://www.curlybrace.com/words/2012/12/17/setting-global-c-include-paths-in-visual-studio-2012-and-2011-and-2010/)
2. Find the files themselves (they are located in *%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0*), open them using your favourite text editor and do your magic. The files are XML-based so it's not awfully difficult.